# Validate Zipcode using api in php

Tags: php, api, validation

I want to validate that zip code entered by user is valid or not.

for example user entered 009876654 and it is not valid then an error
message should be given.

I know i can do it using javascript regulr expression or using
ajax-zip-code-database

But i don't want any of the above. i need some plugin sort of thing
which send request to some online application to check wheather it is
valid or not.I want this because i don't want to take care if in future
there is change in the zip-codes or new zip-codes get added.

P.S. :- I don't want to use javascript or using ajax-zip-code-database

Answer (score 3):

USPS provides a list of API service providers that support ZIP Code Lookup: https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-service-providers.htm